# Merge a Product Config JSON with Generic Config JSON- Issue While Merging Arrays inside it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge, lodash

I have 2 different Json files
1: a Deaflut JSON file
2: A Product Based JSON file

I need to merge them together in such a way that if a feature in default is not in a product that needs to be added to product config from default one.
for this merge, I used "lodash.mergewith" https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.mergewith.
so this is now taking care of the merge, But the file contains multiple nested JSON arrays inside it.

to handle that there is an option to use a customizer method that can handle array merge as mentioned in the usage of lodash.mergewith. I need a customizer that can find the Label from Deaflut and compare it with the Product if the Product has the same Label value then replace the URL with the Product URL. else if the Label is not in Product config, then use it from default as it is.

**Example**

**Default config.json:-links is an array of this json with path : object►login►options►sections►2►links**

```js
"links": [{
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Lable1"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label2"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label3"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label4"
    }
]
```

**Productconfig.json:- links is an array inside this of the path: object►login►options►sections►2►links**

```js
"links": [{
        "url": "www.product1.com",
        "label": "label1"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.product2.com",
        "label": "Label2"
    }
]
```

** after merge mergedconfig.json  "Links" need to be like this.**

```js
"links": [{
        "url": "www.product1.com",
        "label": "Label1"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.product2.com",
        "label": "Label2"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label3"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label4"
    }
]
```

The main concern is this Array is coming inside a JSON file inside some JSON objects

like eg if the Array is inside links[] it will be in a path like : object►login►options►sections►2►links[]. and this Links Array similarly present inside in some other paths eg: object►register►options►sections►2►links[]

So I need to figure out all the Array like this and for each of the Arrays, I need to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.map` and `Array.find`:

```js
let links= [
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label1"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label2"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label3"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "label": "Label4"
    }
];

let plinks= [{
        "url": "www.product1.com",
        "label": "label1"
    },
    {
        "url": "www.product2.com",
        "label": "Label2"
    }
];

let results = links.map(lnk=>{
  plnk = plinks.find(pl=>pl.label.toLowerCase()===lnk.label.toLowerCase());
  return plnk || lnk
});

console.log(results);
```

for clean access to nested `JSON` keys you can use `ES` like this:

```js
let a = {
  b: {
    c: [1,2,3]
  }
};

let {c} = a?.b;
console.log(c);
```

Comment: I need to perform this action on each array in my config.json: There will be multiple arrays inside config.json. and I have to perform this action in each of them